# Pass each nested list as an arg to map

Tags: python-2.7

I have a nested list as follows:

```
[[u'56', u'99', u'160'], [u'74', u'113', u'169'], [u'92', u'127', u'177'], [u'110', u'142', u'186'], [u'128', u'156', u'195'], [u'146', u'170', u'203'], [u'165', u'184', u'212'], [u'183', u'198', u'220'], [u'201', u'212', u'229'], [u'219', u'227', u'238'], [u'237', u'241', u'246']]
```

I want to pass each list as a sequence to the following map function:

```
map(None, nested_list1, nested_list2 ...]
```

So that, I get 3 lists, where, the first list contains the first element from all the nested_lists, the second list contains the second element from all the nested_lists.

So far, after many tries, I have come up with the following code (it does not involve map()).

```
first_list = [each[0] for each in nested_list]
second_list = [each[1] for each in nested_list]
third_list = [each[1] for each in nested_list]
```

I think this can be made into a one-liner if map() is used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `zip` but you can do it with `map`, you just have to use  `*list_of_lists` to transpose:

```
a, b, c = map(None,*l)
```

If you want list you would have to also map to list:

```
map(None,*l)
```

Really you should use zip:

```
a,b,c = map(list,zip(*l))
```

Both will give the  same output in python 2:

```
In [19]: a,b,c = map(list,map(None,*l))
In [20]: print a
[u'56', u'74', u'92', u'110', u'128', u'146', u'165', u'183', u'201', u'219', u'237']

In [21]: print b
[u'99', u'113', u'127', u'142', u'156', u'170', u'184', u'198', u'212', u'227', u'241']

In [22]: print c
[u'160', u'169', u'177', u'186', u'195', u'203', u'212', u'220', u'229', u'238', u'246']
In [23]: a,b,c = map(list, zip(*l))

In [24]: print a
[u'56', u'74', u'92', u'110', u'128', u'146', u'165', u'183', u'201', u'219', u'237']

In [25]: print b
[u'99', u'113', u'127', u'142', u'156', u'170', u'184', u'198', u'212', u'227', u'241']

In [26]: print c
[u'160', u'169', u'177', u'186', u'195', u'203', u'212', u'220', u'229', u'238', u'246']
```

But the `map` approach won't work using python3.